# I can't find the debug.keystore file

Tags: java, android, eclipse, certificate, keystore

I'm having an error with Eclipse and Android's SDK. apparently, it comes from the fact that my certificate expired. So I googled the error and I found that I have to remove the ~/.android/debug.keystore file. The thing is I can't find this file. It's not in my SDK.

Can someone help me with this ?

Edit: I work on Mac.

Comment: Which OS are you running? ~/.android/debug.keystore will only work on unix like operating systems

Comment: and %USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore will work on windows

Comment: OSX 10.6 If I remember correctly.

Answer (score 121):

Open Eclipse Preferences, then navigate to **Android** > **Build**. There you'll see a field that tells the location of your debug keystore.

Comment: Where is it in android studio

Answer (score 25):

On Linux / OSX use your favorite terminal and type `rm ~/.android/debug.keystore` to remove the debug keystore.

You can create a new keystore after that by [following these steps](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#debugmode).

Comment: the thing is with the cd command, I manage to go to smthg like ~/Documents/Work/Workspace/SDK Android(which is where i put my android sdk)/.DS_Store    and there, when i push tab there is the .android/debug.keystore file. But it makes no sense, it seems to be in a file.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it is in the `.android/avd/` directory in OSX, but it could also be just in `/.android/` as you suggest.

Remember that `~` means your home directory, so you do not need to look for it in your SDK!

(disclaimer) It's been a while since [I've battled with this](http://androblip.huiges.nl/2010/08/25/android-debug-key-expiration-sdkeclipse/), and I didn't do it on a mac.

Answer (score 2):

Expiry of the Debug Certificate

The self-signed certificate used to sign your application in debug mode (the default on Eclipse/ADT and Ant builds) will have an expiration date of 365 days from its creation date.

When the certificate expires, you will get a build error. On Ant builds, the error looks like this:

debug:
[echo] Packaging bin/samples-debug.apk, and signing it with a debug key...
[exec] Debug Certificate expired on 8/4/08 3:43 PM
In Eclipse/ADT, you will see a similar error in the Android console.

To fix this problem, simply delete the debug.keystore file. The default storage location for AVDs is in ~/.android/ on OS X and Linux, in C:\Documents and Settings\.android\ on Windows XP, and in C:\Users\.android\ on Windows Vista and Windows 7.

Source: Android Publishing Guide:
http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: Yeah I know all this. The thing is, there is no debug.keystore file in mine. And that's my problem btw...