# Developing Android application on multiple computers with Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-sdk-tools

I have my Android application project in Dropbox folder. I use my desktop pc as well as my laptop to develop the application. When I switch between these two computers, it uses some kind of different key or something for the application and Android SDK says I have to first uninstall (and lost all data) before I can install it again.

Any fixes?

Comment: http://bitbucket.org is a great site for personal repositories.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you should be using a Version Control System such as SVN, Git, TFS, CVS, etc. it sounds like you have an issue with the developer key used to sign the application.  I haven't used Eclipse in over a year since I prefer using IntelliJ however I will answer from what I remember about Eclipse and the Android SDK.

The Android SDK has a default keystore that is used for signing development applications (on Windows it should be in C:\Users\username\.android\debug.keystore, on Mac it is /Users/username/.android/debug.keystore).  If you want to be able to debug your application on multiple computers without uninstalling the APK first then you will need to copy one of these debug.keystore files to the other machine.

Now, as I mentioned I haven't used Eclipse in some time so Eclipse may use a different location/keystore combination (I know IntelliJ does) however the same method can be used.

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9398019/i-cant-find-the-debug-keystore-file/9398619#9398619

Answer (score 6):

Use subversion or git for your source control. Dropbox is not sufficient, since it won't even log history.

For subversion, I recommend google code with subversive eclipse plugin: 
https://code.google.com
For git, you should use (with git eclipse plugin)
https://github.com/

Comment: +1, though I would describe this as "source control," not "versioning."

Comment: And just to add to your post. In my early days, I once tried using drop box for just this. I learned the hard way that deleting something on one computer deleted it on all of them.

Comment: Well, thanks for your answer. This wasn't quite what I wanted, but seems okay. Not sure why I didn't think of version control systems, I even have one running on my server...

Comment: Git works you just have to import the project. You can't directly put it in the workspace it won't recognized it.