# Why is Re-installation failed due to different application signatures?

Tags: android, eclipse

I developed an android application successfully and then that application import another computer's eclipse then shows:

```
[2014-04-17 22:13:06 - application] Launch canceled!
[2014-04-17 22:13:07 - application] Re-installation failed due to different application signatures.
[2014-04-17 22:13:07 - application] You must perform a full uninstall of the application. WARNING: This will remove the application data!
[2014-04-17 22:13:07 - application] Please execute 'adb uninstall com.databizsoftware.cg' in a shell.
[2014-04-17 22:13:07 - application] Launch canceled!
```

then i try to solve this verities ways: such as

1) delete bin folder and gen folder
2) clean this application
3) eclipse restart.

But show same problem.

How to solve this problem. Please help me.

Comment: because each dev environment has a specific signature by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem, simply uninstall the current application from the test device, and try launching again. Do not do this if you would like to persist application preferences and other data on the device.

Answer (score 2):

This is because your application is signed with a different debug key on each of the computers.

You can, however, overwrite the key from computer A with computer B's. Then they'll be signed with the same key. <s>I don't remember where this key resides, however.</s>

According to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9398619/2155492

> Open Eclipse Preferences, then navigate to Android > Build. There you'll see a field that tells the location of your debug keystore.